# How can i have a java interface return an object of a non primitive type?

Tags: java, android, oop, interface

Can java interface methods can only return primitive types (int,string,etc?)

I want to have a method return a type "BitMap". But my IDE is complaining with Cannot resolve symbol "BitMap":

```
public interface MyContract {
    public BitMap getBitMap();
    ....
```

I suspect I'm misunderstanding something inherent to interfaces that is preventing me from doing this?

Comment: You are probably missing an import statement.

Comment: isn't  it `Bitmap` instead of `BitMap` unless it's a customize class

Comment: ugh typo, im dumb, ok deleting this. welp too late

Comment: `String` is not a primitive type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can java interface methods can only return primitive types (int,string,etc?)

No, they can return any valid data type.

> I want to have a method return a type "BitMap". But my IDE is complaining with Cannot resolve symbol "BitMap":

There is no type named `BitMap` visible to this Java source file. You are missing an `import` statement. And, perhaps, there is a typo in the type name. For example, [on Android, `android.graphics.Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) does not have a capital M in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can return any object type.

Try `Bitmap` instead

Answer (score 0):

> Can java interface methods can only return primitive types (int,string,etc?)

It doesn't matter whether you are returning an Object or a primitive for an abstract method in Java.

Make sure you are making the necessary imports or typing the right class name, it seems that your IDE problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error and a suggestion right here **assuming you meant the standard Bitmap class and not a custom one**:

1. *BitMap* is written `Bitmap`
2. `Interfaces` have no privacy keyword so you can remove `public` from your method since it's redundant.

This should be the result

```
public interface IMyContract {
    Bitmap getBitMap();
    ....
}
```

Anyway you can return any type you want from an interface, there are no limitation of this kind

Answer (score 0):

You can return a reference type (for example, try with Object).

1. Check for import the package in which the class is defined.
2. Check whether the class has the appropriate access modifier after you have inserted the package.